# Cisco router auto restart in x seconds

Tags: router, reboot

Once I used a command to have the router restart in * seconds (or minutes), but now I forgot the command.

How can I have the router restart in * amount of time, so if I make configuration changes that are not correct, they are ***undone*** after the auto restart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a reload command, e.g.:

`reload in 1:00` - restart the router in one hour.

`reload in 10` - restart the router in 10 minutes

Or you can use `reload at` to restart at a specified time. E.g.:

`reload at 13:00` - restart the router at 1:00 PM

`reload at 9:00 May 25` - restart the router at 9:00 AM on May 25

You can use `reload cancel` to cancel a scheduled restart.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the archive feature and rollback changes: http://www.ciscozine.com/reload-in-x-why-dont-you-rollback-or-replace-the-configuration/

But relo in x is the easiest and fastest way to do it. It has saved me several times.

This is a much better way of controlling versions then just copying running config to Flash. You can have the router automatically back itself up.

R5(config)#archive !   you need to set the archive up first
R5(config-archive)#path !   you have to set the path where the files will go
R5(config-archive)#path ?
  ftp:    Write archive on ftp: file system
  http:   Write archive on http: file system
  https:  Write archive on https: file system
  pram:   Write archive on pram: file system
  rcp:    Write archive on rcp: file system
  scp:    Write archive on scp: file system
  tftp:   Write archive on tftp: file system

R5(config-archive)#path tftp://10.30.0.62/R5
R5(config-archive)#time-period ? !the router can automatically back itself up
  <1-525600>  Number of minutes to wait between archive creation

R5(config-archive)#time-period 10080!   one a week

archive
path tftp://10.30.0.62/R5
 time-period 10080

archive config !   forced the archive. This should be done before anyone makes any changes to the router, especially clients that are far from us.
!!
R5#c
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
R5(config)#host not-R5!    made some changes 
not-R5(config)#^Z

not-R5#b tftp://10.30.0.62/R5-1 list time 10! restoring the old config, and list the changes
!!Timed Rollback: Backing up to tftp://10.30.0.62/R5-4

This will apply all necessary additions and deletions
to replace the current running configuration with the
contents of the specified configuration file, which is
assumed to be a complete configuration, not a partial
configuration. Enter Y if you are sure you want to proceed. ? [no]: y
Loading R5-1 from 10.30.0.62 (via FastEthernet0/1): !
[OK - 3135 bytes]
!Pass 1

!List of Commands:!   what it changed back
no hostname not-R5
hostname R5
end

Total number of passes: 1
Rollback Done

R5#!    back to original config

R5#show archive config differences ! this will show you what is different in the running config vs. what is in the archived config. Answers the question “what has changed on the router”.
Contextual Config Diffs:
-username remove-me password 0 askdjhfr80

Comment: Could you quote the relevant parts from your link in case it is removed in the future? Please see [answer] for more details.